# What MAPI Property determines if a meeting has not been sent yet?

Tags: outlook, outlook-2010, mapi

Does anybody know what MAPI property determines whether a meeting item has not been sent yet?  Currently, outlook displays a "Invitations have not been sent for this meeting." message at the top.

(e.g. this is a new meeting item).  See screenshot below.

[image: MAPI Property to determine "Invitations have not been sent for this meeting."]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FInvited - it is a PT_BOOLEAN named property with GUID = {00062002-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} (PSETID_Appointment) and id = 0x8229.

Comment: Thank you!  I was actually reading another one of your responses on another forum found here: http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/Outlook/microsoft.public.outlook.program_forms/2008-06/msg00085.html before posting this question.